# GWT Client and Server

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-ext, gxt

I believe that GWT achieves RIA through initial throwing of 
objects and files to the client side initially. but what I do not 
understand is that is it possible to control the amount of information 
being thrown to the client side? cos this is because I do not want 
sensitive information to be cache at the client side. these 
information shall only be retrieved from server when requested. 
these information should only be sent to the client only when 
requested and should not be cached at the client side. does anyone 
know if it is possible to control the amount of information being sent 
to the client? can anyone enlighten me? would appreciate your help 
sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

See if you dont want to expose particular information on client side then keep it on server side and whenever you want that information then using RPC call you can get it on server side.And gwt cache things like images etc that on client side information only.It is not caching your information which is present in lets say database or server side.So you dont need to worry about it.And if you want more security then you can use encryption and decryption algorithms.And if you follow design patterns like mvc then that will be very good programming practice.I created one sample application so if you want you can take checkout from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mvc-pattern/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your information. I don't see anything from the sample application you created. How do I download or view it? Also, I would like to know if it is necessary that the design pattern must be MVC. Cos currently I identified mine as 3-Tier. Will it affect? thanks once again.

Comment: Another question I would like to ask is, that how do you define what 
information is going to be cache on the client side? is it that you paste your images into .client file?

thanks once again.